# How to add zeros and limit to 8 digits using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame column that's composed of numbers.
It's necessary to add zeros to the left if some elements don't reach 8 digits.

ex:

| column1 |
| --- |
| 81234567 |
| 1294569 |
| 23479 |

It needs to be like:

| column1 |
| --- |
| 81234567 |
| 01294569 |
| 00023479 |

Comment: note that in order to do this, you will have to convert the data to string types, which means math will not work anymore. if you'd prefer to just change the display of the data (not affect the values) you can use [pandas display options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```py
df["column1"] = df["column1"].astype(str).str.zfill(8)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    column1
0  81234567
1  01294569
2  00023479
```